# android logback does not rollover on time based policy

Tags: android, logback

I am using android logback to write into an internal folder.

my logger configuration looks like this:

```
<configuration debug='true'>
<property name="LOG_DIR" value="logs" />

<appender name="logcat" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
    <tagEncoder>
        <pattern>%logger{12} %-5level</pattern>
    </tagEncoder>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!-- active log file -->
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/log.txt</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd.MM HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.txt</fileNamePattern>

        <maxHistory>4</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="logcat"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

the file name pattern "log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.txt" should create a new log file for every minute (since minutes are the smallest unit).
the rollback is triggered, but it fails and the debug message just says:

```
|-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - RolloverFailure occurred. Deferring rollover
```

The log.txt file is written correctly, but it fails on the rollover.
I am writing into internal storage, so permissions are no problems (and I also have the writing on external sd card permission already).

edit: I just tested it with the external sd as log destination and there it seems to work. So it seems the logback can write the actual log file into the internal storage but can not rollover (probably due to wrong access rights?).

Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fileNamePattern` in `RollingFileAppender` must be an absolute path, or else it [incorrectly] traverses the rollover-file path from the root directory (i.e., `/logs`). You can work around the issue in your example by setting the `LOG_DIR` property to `/data/data/<package-name>/files/logs`.

---

It seems another user reported this exact [issue](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues/117).

Comment: thx. for the other users the best way seems to be (as you answered in that issue) to use:
 <file>${DATA_DIR}/log/currentlog.txt</file>
as a file location for both the current log as well as the rollover stuff.

Comment: [`${DATA_DIR}`](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues/110#issuecomment-196305259) is a special variable for `/data/data/<package-name>/files`. Setting `LOG_DIR` would effectively yield the same result.